# Why is it ok to do "new" to an abstract class?

Tags: java, class, abstract

In the following code, i was thinking there would be an error because of the line "new Calculate" because
it is an abstract class. Why is this code working?

```
abstract class Calculate
{
  abstract int multiply(int a, int b);
}

public class Main
{
  public static void main(String[]args)
 {
   int result = new Calculate()
   {
        @Override
        int multiply(int a, int b)
        {
           return a*b;
        }
   }   .multiply(12,32);
 }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. what language is this ? Please add the language tag to the question.

Comment: Hey, it is java language.

Comment: are you sure the code formatting is correct ? Something is off with the format.

Comment: It was a question i saw in a website asking if the code will run correctly, and the answer is yes. I though it wouldn't run because of the line "new calculate" because it is an asbtract class

Comment: https://www.edureka.co/community/33043/is-there-a-way-to-instantiate-abstract-class This explains things more clearly.